# Does WPF have GUI layers in the editor?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a single window that does initialization first, and then those controls fade out as the Menu controls fade in. Depending on what the user clicks next, the current menu controls will fade out for the next set of controls to fade in.

While developing in the editor (Visual Studio 2017), I often have to hide and show certain controls so I can see the current 'screen layer' I'm interested in.

While I'm working in the editor, is there a way to click on layers in WPF like clicking on tabs? You can think of tabs like "Layer 1" on the window has the initialization controls, then Layer 2 has the menu controls, etc. Then just show/hide layers while developing in the editor like you would in paint programs. I'm just thinking that would make development easier.

Comment: You could sort of mimic this by using a container `Grid` with a child layout container for each "layer".  You would have to manually toggle the visibility of each container to get the ones you want hidden / visible, and also remember to make them all visible before running the application.  It all seems like a lot of extra work though.  Erno's `UserControl` solution is far superior.

Comment: @BradleyUffner - Hidden/visible would not work. It would be easier to move the control you want to work on to be the last child control in the grid. Still annoying in my opinion.

Comment: Ahh,true. I forgot that the designer ignores it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no standard way built-in to Visual Studio.

I strongly suggest to split the layers into (user)controls, this way the designer can focus on one thing at the time.